# CSS: element should get max-width before breaking words

Tags: css, tooltip, word-break

There are CSS tooltips (codepen is given below). They have `min-width` and `max-width`. They contain sometimes short phrases, sometimes very long words without breaks. This is what happens if there is `white-space: nowrap` => Short tooltips are rendered perfectly, but long ones, obviously, are not wrapped and are not fully visible:

[image: description]

This is what happens when I add `white-space: normal` and `word-break: break-word` => Now short ones and long ones get wrapped long before getting to the `max-width`:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is:
Tooltips don't wrap before getting to the max-width. And start wrapping only if they don't get into the max-width. Like here:

[image]

Is it possible to get this behaviour just with CSS (no javascript)?

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWXobM 
(Uncomment lines 58-59 to change the behaviour.)

*I didn't manage to achieve this with any of the found solutions. If you know how to apply them in this case, please share!*

Update: apparently some kind of solution to this problem has just been added to the wg draft: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1171. It is still interesting if someone found a workaround for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and was able to use a wrapping element to style it the way I wanted. I forked a previous answer's codepen and got it to work based on what I am assuming you wanted: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BONWGG

the key changes were creating a new element for the `[data-tooltip]`, giving it column flex, and letting the `::after` element scale as big as it needs to

```html
<span class="tooltip-container">
  Tooltip 1 should be on 1 line
  <span data-tooltip="Short"></span>
</span>
```

---

```css
[data-tooltip] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  &::after {
    ...
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
}
.tooltip-container {
  ...
  &:hover {
    [data-tooltip] {
      display: flex;
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Though adding another node, still very nice solution with flex-shrink.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are too verbose or insufficient. What I added was `width:max-content;` which works rather intuitively since its trying to maximise the width, but will stop at the `max-width` and then breaks the overflow through either `word-break:break-all;`, `word-wrap:break-word;` or `overflow-wrap:break-word;`

Here is the CSS (SCSS) to answer OP, you can test it via the codepen in OP's question, just paste it.

```
@keyframes show-vert {
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    opacity: .9;
  }
}
@keyframes show-diag {
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: .9;
  }
}
body {
  background: #eaeaea;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
span {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 8px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  z-index: auto !important;
  &::before, &::after {
    content: '';
    display: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1;
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  &::before {
    z-index: 1001;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
  }
  &::after {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    z-index: 1000;
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 280px;
    height: auto;
    //changes - removed
    //width: 100%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    background: hsla(0, 0%, 38%, 1);
    box-shadow: 0 1em 2em -.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    //changes - added
    word-break: break-all;
    width: max-content;
  }
  &:hover {
    &::before, &::after {
      display: block;
    }
    &::after {
      //changes - removed
      // width: auto;
    }
  }
}

[data-tooltip] {
  &.tooltip-down {
    &::before {
      top: 100%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, .5em);
      border-top-width: 0;
      border-bottom-color: hsla(0, 0%, 38%, 1);
    }
    &::after {
      left: 50%;
      top: calc(100% + 5px);
      transform: translate(-50%, .5em);
    }
    &:hover {
      &::before, &::after {
        animation: show-vert 500ms linear 1ms forwards;
      }
    }
  }
  &.tooltip-down-left {
    &::before {
      left: 1em;
    }
    &::after {
      left: 0;
    }
    &::before, &::after {
      transform: translate(-1em, -.5em);
    }
    &:hover{
      &::before, &::after {
        animation: show-diag 500ms linear 1ms forwards;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `word-break: break-word` as it is breaking every word to new line, instead use `overflow-wrap: break-word;` and `white-space: normal`.

Comment: Here is my try of what you suggest: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgPobX 
As you can see the second tooltip is broken into too lines (it should be on one line as it is shorter than the max-width). The third tooltip is on one line and it should break on several lines. Please, make a codepen with what you have in mind.

Comment: in your codepen the second tooltip "Here be dragons" breaks on 2 lines, though it is not necessary at all. And I am looking for solution where it stays on one line.

Comment: I am not getting what you are saying. It is showing in one line "Here be dragons".  where line is breaking?

Comment: Aman, I tried in the latest Chrome and Firefox on Windows8 and on Edge on Windows7 and Windows8, and everywhere "Here be dragons" is on 2 lines. I have screenshots, let me know if you want them. (Edge even doesn't wrap the long comment: it stays on one line with ellipses at the end of the line. But I don't care about Edge.) In which browser you have a good result?

Comment: I have checked in firefox and yes it is showing in two line. The problem is you need to apply a certain width to absolute element and you need to tweak you animation also then may be it'll get fixed.

Comment: Aman, width should be automatic, because I don't know how long can be the text for the tooltip: it can be one word or a very long phrase. What do you mean by tweaking the animation? How can this help?

Answer (score 0):

I made some changed in the css code.I have commented on the lines which i have changed.(eg. //changed).Actually you already made the half solution by using

```
word-break: break-word;
```

The only thing i changed is min-width and max-width to achieve the required results.

Here is the updated link

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyGpaL

Comment: Thank you for this interesting solution. But now try to make one of the tooltips very short and the tooltip will still be 250px wide. And it shouldn't. The width should adapt to the content.

Comment: but then the tooltip is always 250px wide, and the `min-width` is bigger than the `max-width`. OP wants the tooltip to be as small as the content in it until 280px wide, then it should wrap.