# Force variable width table column contents to wrap at max-width *only*

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table that has the following requirements:

- All columns must have variable widths
- All columns must not take up more width than necessary
- All cells must preserve white-spaces (white-space:pre/pre-wrap)
- All cells must wrap when (and only when) exceeding maximum defined width (1000px)

I'm having trouble accomplishing rule #4.

As long as the whole width of the table fits on screen, there's no problem. However, when the available space is exceeded, the browser will do anything to make it fit by wrapping sooner than I intent. Also smaller columns will decrease in width and start to wrap.

CSS:

```css
table {
    width: auto;
}

table td {
    max-width: 1000px !important;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

HTML:

```
   <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Small text, should not wrap</td>
        <td>Long text, should wrap at 1000px only; [...]</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Please check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2gbL3wv/1/)

I'm using `white-space:pre-wrap`, because the content must be able to wrap, even though the original data doesn't contain newlines. When I use `white-space:pre`, the column widths are exactly right, but obviously the content will overflow beyond the cell. I've tried to overcome this by adding `overflow-wrap:break-word`, but that didn't work..

Comment: I need the answer to this too, but for my case it's for a normal div instead of a table. I think it can be described as: make all lines as long as possible, minimize line breaks.

Comment: I found another question that answers this nicely. [CSS: element should get max-width before breaking words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44393657/css-element-should-get-max-width-before-breaking-words). The solution is to use `::after{flex-shrink:0}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there's no pure-CSS solution to this. In the meantime I've found a reliable work-around with a little bit of html and javascript.

I've put a `<div>` around the table, and gave it a width of `number_of_columns * max_column_width`, essentially the maximum width the table would have if all columns exceed the threshold.

This results in the table being rendered the way I intended, however this obviously causes a horizontal scrollbar reaching way beyond the rendered table. Therefore I need to reduce the width of the `<div>` to the actual width of the rendered table.

```
div.style.width = table.offsetWidth + 'px';
```

Not very elegant, but it does the job.

Comment: Apparently this is not a 100% fix. If the screen width exceeds the minimum width the browser is able to draw the table, it will do so. Once the window is resized to below this width, the table snaps to the desirable format.